# Get application quit signal before windows are closed in QT

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Qt Application with multiple main windows and want to get a signal when the App is about to quit while all windows are still up.

The `QApplication.aboutToQuit` signal doesn't work for me because it only fires after all windows have been closed.

All other answers I've seen suggest implementing the main window's `closeEvent()` function, but I have multiple main windows and I couldn't find any way to differentiate `CloseEvent`s between a normal `closeEvent` of just a single window being closed and a close event from when the whole application is closing after `QMD+Q` or the using clicking quit in the task bar or for whatever reason it quits.

How do I get a signal for that only when the whole application is about to quit but before any windows are closed?

What happens when I press Cmd+Q or right click quit the task bar icon:

1. (I want a signal at this point) <-
2. all windows get a closeEvent()
3. aboutToQuit() fires
4. app quits

What I want is to get a signal before any of that happens and all the windows are still open.

Edit: minimal example

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCloseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

class Win(QWidget):
    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        # implementing a custom closeEvent doesn't help me
        # this is called for every normal manual window close and when the application quits
        # I only want to run something when the full application gets shut down, not just this window
        # can't see any way to differentiate between the two
        print("closeEvent", event.type(), event)
        return super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(lambda :print("about to quit, this is too late, by now all windows are closed"))

    #What I need
    # app.beforeQuitSignal.connect(lambda :print("signal that it's gonna quit, before any of the windows are closed"))

    #stuff I've tried that didn't work either
    app.quit = lambda *args:print("quit, doesnt get called")
    app.exit = lambda *args:print("exit, doesnt get called")
    app.closeAllWindows = lambda *args:print("closeAllWindows, doesnt get called")

    mainwins = []
    for i in range(5):
        win = Win()
        win.setGeometry(100*i,100*i, 400,400), win.show(), win.raise_()
        mainwins.append(win)

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your application (not the complete one !).
I would suggest you to reimplement `closeEvent()` for each `QMainWindow` and emit custom signal from here with a slot in your `QApplication` but maybe it's not suitable for you.

Comment: @LoïcG. added example now, but `closeEvent` doesn't help, that gets called every time a window is closed by the user as well, I want it to only run when the whole application exits after Alt F4 etc.

Comment: @Stitch95 That is, you want a signal that alerts you a moment before all the windows close, and also tells you if the last window was closed with close or not.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes I just want a aboutToQuit signal but before any of the windows are actually closed. I don't care how the last window was closed before or anything, I just added the closeEvent in the example since that was suggested as a solution so I wanted to show why that doesnt work for the way I want it

Comment: Can not you just set `QApplication.quitOnLastWindowClosed` to False in order to do not exit immediately after the last windows is closed and doing what you want to do before exiting the app ?

Comment: Explain yourself better, your explanation is confusing.!!!!

Comment: @eyllanesc I've updated the post now to be more clear now, but in the answer you gave after CMD+Q was pressed all the closeEvents() for all the open windows where still called *before* the beforeClosed() signal you made was emitted, then the signal was called, and then the closeEvent()s of the windows were called again afterwards. I just want to know that the application is about to quit and all the windows will be closed before those windows are actually closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fire a signal when the user close a window but do not exit the `QApplication` immediately after the last window is closed, you can use `QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed()`

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCloseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Win(QWidget):
    closing = pyqtSignal()

    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        print("Window {} closed".format(self))
        self.closing.emit()
        return super().closeEvent(event)


class MyApp(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args)

        self.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
        self.lastWindowClosed.connect(self.onLastClosed)

        self.mainwins = []
        for i in range(5):
            win = Win()
            win.setGeometry(100 * i, 100 * i, 400, 400), win.show(), win.raise_()
            self.mainwins.append(win)

    def onLastClosed(self):
        print("Last windows closed, exiting ...")
        self.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp([])
    app.exec_()
```

With this, when a window is closed, a `closing()` signal is emited

Comment: thanks but I just want a signal when the app is about to shut down (because of CMD+Q or because the use clicked quit on the task bar or for whatever reason the app shuts down) but before any of the windows are closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the `CloseEvent` if it is `spontaneous` :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCloseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Win(QWidget):
    closing = pyqtSignal()
    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        self.closing.emit()
        if event.type() == QEvent.Close and event.spontaneous():
            event.ignore()
        else:
            return super().closeEvent(event)


class MyApp(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args)

        self.mainwins = []
        for i in range(5):
            win = Win()
            win.closing.connect(self.beforeQuit)
            win.setGeometry(100 * i, 100 * i, 400, 400), win.show(), win.raise_()
            self.mainwins.append(win)

    def beforeQuit(self):
        print("Exiting")
        # Do what you want here ...
        self.exit()  # Terminate the QApplication

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp([])
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me on OSX, that also exits when I just close any window, not just when I close the whole application.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "close the whole application" but the code above exits because `self.exit()` is called in `beforeQuit()` (at least on Windows). So `beforeQuit` is called when any window is closed and from here you can do anything you want.

Comment: Yes but I dont want it to run when any window is closed, I only want it to run when the whole application will be closed because of alt+f4.

Comment: Alt+F4 only close window for me. With your code, the application close only when the 5 windows are closed, so after 5 * Alt+F4

Comment: If you want to be able to close each `QWidget` but do not want the `QApplication` exits when the last widget is closed, you may take a look at the `QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed()` method

Comment: ohh I see, that explains the confusion then, sorry, CMD+Q instantly quits the whole application for me on OSX the first time and sends a close to every window, so I have no way of telling if a window close comes from the whole application quitting or just because the user clicked the X on that window.

Comment: @Stitch95, I added an another solution based on `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed()`. Hope it would help

Comment: @Stitch95 I read again your last comment here and your question (and it's edit) and I do not understand why this solution is not suitable for you. It seems that your problem is OSX related. With this solution, if the close event comes from the window system (spontaneous event), then it is ignored and the window is not closed. For closing in, you need to explicitely close the `QApplication` using `QApplication.self()` (which is called into `beforeQuit()`). Maybe `CMD + Q` sends a `SIGKILL` signal or equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Use `installEventFilter` to intercept the application's quit event before any windows are closed:

```
class AppManager(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Quit:
            self.saveWindowStates()
        return False

    def saveWindowStates(self):
        # code to save the application's state
```